# How can I test a socket.io server with multiple clients?

Tags: testing, socket.io

I'm trying to write tests for a socket.io server.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('say', function (msg) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('update', msg);
  });
});
```

Each client receives all messages sent by the others​. I just want to test that.

To do this, my test needs to simulate multiple clients. But ​`socket.io-client​` reuses connections, which makes that hard.

How should I test this code?

Answer (score 3):

Found it. When creating the client, use the option [`multiplex: false`](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#io%28url:string,-opts:object%29:socket):

```
var client = io("http://localhost:3000", {multiplex: false});
```

According to the documentation:

> When called, `io()` creates a new `Manager` for the given URL, and attempts to reuse an existing `Manager` for subsequent calls, unless the
>   `multiplex` option is passed with `false`. Passing this option is the equivalent of passing `'force new connection': true`.